# The intersection $\bigcap_{i \in I}G_i$ is an order relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $\{G_i\}_{i \in I}$ be an indexed family of order relations in a set $A$. Show that $\bigcap_{i \in I}G_i$ is an order relation in $A$.

My attempt:

Since $G_i$ is reflexive for all $i \in I$,

$\forall x \in A, (x,x) \in G_i \forall i \in I$

$\implies \forall x \in A, (x,x) \in \bigcap_{i \in I}G_i$

Is this the right way of proving the reflexive part?
And could anyone help me with the antisymmetric and transitive part. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G = \displaystyle \bigcap_{i \in I} G_i$.

### Reflexivity

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\forall x \in A: && \forall i \in I:  (x,x) \in G_i \\
&\implies& (x,x) \in G
\end{array}$$

### Antisymmetry

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\forall x,y \in A: && (x,y) \in G \land (y,x) \in G \\
&\implies& \forall i \in I: (x,y) \in G_i \land (y,x) \in G_i \\
&\implies& x = y
\end{array}$$

### Transitivity

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\forall x,y,z \in A: && (x,y) \in G \land (y,z) \in G \\
&\implies& \forall i \in I: (x,y) \in G_i \land (y,z) \in G_i \\
&\implies& \forall i \in I: (x,z) \in G_i \\
&\implies& (x,z) \in G
\end{array}$$

Comment: Check that Antisymmetry proof

Comment: @amrsa Thank you, fixed.

Comment: No, you must conclude that $x=y$.

Comment: @amrsa I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: I've attempted to help, below

Answer (score 0):

For each `i : I` we have an order relation `Gᵢ`, and their intersection
`G ≔ ∩ᵢ Gᵢ` is also an order relation.

Indeed, it is reflexive: For any element `x` we have,

```
   x G x
 =⟨ definition of G and intersection membership ⟩
   ∀ i : I  • x Gᵢ x       -- the bullet is a syntactic separator only
 =⟨ each Gᵢ is reflexive ⟩
   ∀ i : I • true
 =⟨ quantifiers ⟩
   true
```

Likewise, it is antisymmetric: For any element `x` and element `y`,

```
   x G y  ∧  y G x
 =⟨ definition of G, intersection membership, quantifiers ⟩
   ∀ i,j : I •  x Gᵢ y ∧ y Gⱼ x
 ⇒⟨ instantiating j ≔ i ⟩
   ∀ i : I •  x Gᵢ y ∧ y Gᵢ x
 =⟨ each Gᵢ is antisymmetric ⟩
   ∀ i : I • x ≈ y
 =⟨ quantifiers, assuming I non-empty ⟩
   x ≈ y
```

Transitivity is similar :-)